# Image Display Error

Tags: php, asp.net, image, visual-studio-2012, razor

```
  <div class="result">
        <img src="@imagePath" alt="image" />
    </div>
```

I want to add an image by providing the link to the image  `@imagePath`. It provides the path `images\IMG_20150507_153730.JPG`

On the display image tag i get always image thumbnail with text image. Because of `alt="image`

The Folder that contains the Images are in the parent folder. Images folder contain the images that presents in the same directory where the file of code is.

Hierarchy of folders

Project Location - `C:\Users\ahsan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\taskCOMSATS`

Code file Location - `C:\Users\ahsan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\taskCOMSATS\upload_image`

Images Folder Location - `C:\Users\ahsan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\taskCOMSATS\images\IMG_20150507_153730.JPG`

Comment: `php`, `asp.net` and with `VS-2012` Are you sure about tags?

Comment: How you assign value to the `@imagePath`?

Comment: yes am sure .....

Comment: hmm..because your code look like php and you're working on visual studio..hahaha

Comment: @Div what you want

Comment: *I think your issue has been resolved?*

Comment: yes... now i have new issue

Comment: You can create new question and ask on SO!

Comment: i posted it... But didn't get answer yet :( [link to new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226774/var-gives-the-result-webmatrix-data-dynamicrecord)

Comment: Because you're not cleared at all

Comment: now what is missing? let me know

Comment: *share the question with your colleagues and ask them to understand it* if he/she can, then you're cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
..\images\IMG_20150507_153730.JPG
```

Comment: how to provide it in Src?

Comment: src="..\images\IMG_20150507_153730.JPG"

Comment: or 
src="taskCOMSATS\images\IMG_20150507_153730.JPG"